# watchos gauge complication like activity

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch-complication

The CLKGaugeProvider has a fillFraction that can only be set between 0 and 1. 
On the activity complication if I move more than my goals the gauge shows more than 100%. 
How can I achieve the same result in a gauge or ring complication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple supplies no complication provider class which can do this on its own.

You’ll need to implement your own custom drawing code, as part of a [`CLKImageProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clkimageprovider) or [`CLKFullColorImageProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clkfullcolorimageprovider), to make this work.